# Does Latex support calligraphic Greek letters?

Tags: greek, letters, calligraphy

I know we have `\mathcal` for calligraphic Latin letters. But it does not work for Greek letters. For example, if I add `\mathcal` before a Greek letter, say `\mathcal\Beta`, the output is the same as the Greek letter alone. But I know there is a calligraphic version of Greek letters, like [this one](https://images.app.goo.gl/cvkCzxGUc7WcTQTz7). So, does Latex support calligraphic Greek letters and, if yes, what is the Latex command for calligraphic Greek letters? Thanks.

Comment: While I don’t know the answer to your question, I’ll remark that quite a few of those calligraphic Greek letters are close to or identical to the calligraphic versions of similar Latin letters. For instance, your calligraphic beta is indistinguishable from `\mathcal{B}`. And even the calligraphic uppercase Gamma could easily be mistaken for a `\mathcal{F}`.

Comment: Welcome. // If the calligraphy is available as a font: yes. If you only have images, you‘d need to turn it, or obtain it, as an adapted bitmap font. So it all boils down to fonts.

Comment: If possible, can you show some image of characters, what you want

Comment: you can use any font you want. It is easiest to use luatex or xetex if you are using truetype or opentype fonts