Help with unidentified character denoting temperature, 19th century thermodynamics
This may not be the appropriate place to ask such a question, so moderators should feel free to delete.
I am reproducing a text on thermodynamics from the 19th century; one character used to indicate temperature I have been unable to identify, and I'd like to avoid arbitrarily replacing it with another. Does anyone have a clue as to what it is and how—if—it can be got in LaTeX?


Could it be a variant of \vartheta?

Try  \partial  with usepackage{euscript}

The \vartheta is a plausible hypothesis indeed, thank you @Mico. Although the resemblance isn't very clear.

Look like a failed hybrid of  \vartheta with g in Fraktur style.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670114/does-latex-support-calligraphic-greek-letters --- the linked image "θ" is very similar to yours.

Thank you, @Rmano!

Found it! It's the theta in GFS Bodoni Classic. Not exactly the same, but quite near. You may want to try also GFS Göschen from the same site.
After downloading the font, you need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\gfsbodoniclassic}{GFSBodoniClassic.otf}

\newcommand{\VT}{%
  \mathord{%
    \text{\gfsbodoniclassic\symbol{"03B8}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Temperature $\VT$ and $\VT'$ are different.

\end{document}


This is with GFS Göschen

We might slant it to the left.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\gfsgoschen}{GFSGoschen-Italic.otf}[
  FakeSlant=-0.25,
]

\newcommand{\VT}{%
  \mathord{%
    \text{\gfsgoschen\symbol{"03B8}}\mspace{-2mu}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Temperature $\VT$ and $\VT'$ are different.

\end{document}


For pdflatex you can create a PDF file with LuaLaTeX from
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface{\gfsbodoniclassic}{GFSBodoniClassic.otf}

\begin{document}

\gfsbodoniclassic\symbol{"03B8}

\end{document}

Call the file bodonitheta.tex. Then you can do
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\VT}{%
  \mathord{%
    \text{\includegraphics[height=1.1\fontcharht\font`0]{bodonitheta}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Temperature $\VT$ and $\VT'$ are different.

\end{document}


Adjust the scaling to suit.

Great find and great answer, can you explain your use of \includegraphics?

@yannisl The idea is to save the glyph in a PDF file that can be included at will. The height is 10% more than the height of a capital letter in the current font. The factor should be adjusted based on visual appearance.

Thanks I see then easy to work with in all engines and speed things up as well.

THANKS A MILLION! Wonderful!

I would suggest the eucal package and using \partial alhough semantically it should be a theta as per the original which must have been based on some Greek calligraphic font. In Greek the word temperature start from theta thermokrasia. Mico's suggestion of varthetais semantically more correct.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eucal}
\begin{document}

"4° The heat exchanges between the system and the external environment occur exclusively either while all points of the system have the same temperature $\partial$....

\end{document}


Sorry, but with either eucal or euscript the symbol for \partial doesn't change from the standard Computer Modern Math.

@egreg  Ypu better at these things, I am waiting for your answer.

It's a tilted and sheared open theta.
